# HTML / CSS Centered Flexible Size Layout

Tags: html, css

I need to create a landing page which consists of an image with text at the top, a couple of videos under that and a strip line image of 2 pixels which I need it so stick to the bottom.

```
<html>
...
<body>

<img src="topimage.png" alt="" />

<table>
 <tr>
<td>Video 1 here</td>
<td>Video 2 here</td>

<img src="2pixelhightimage.png" alt="" />
```

I basically need it to be centered and look relative to the size of the screen so basically resize to compensate the screen resolution.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know where to start for the flexible part of it as percentage can be very tricky if not done properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it preatty easelly by adding a wrapper to your content and setting left and right margin to auto. Use % instead of pixel.

```
<div class="wrapper">

 <img src="topimage.png" alt="">

 <!-- No need to use table here. Just use divs for layout stuff. -->
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Video 1 here</td>
   <td>Video 2 here</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <img class="fixed" src="2pixelhightimage.png" alt="">

</div>
```

And then the CSS:

```
.wrapper { margin: 0 auto;}
img { max-width:100%; height:auto;}
.fixed {position:fixed; bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this for the general layout?

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="content">content goes here</div>
</div> 

.wrap
{
width:100%;
background:gray;
}
.content
{
width:80%;
margin:0 20%;
background:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k25gU/

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper div around the content

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

and style it like this

```
#wrapper {
    width: 980px /* Maximum width of the content */
    max-width: 100% /* responsive width */
    margin: 0 auto; /* center the wrapper */
}
```

also don't use tables for the videos. Table columns will not break on small screens. Use

```
<ul class="videos">
    <li class="video">
        <!-- content here -->
    </li>
    <li class="video">
        <!-- content here -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

then css them

```
.videos {
    list-style: none; /* no bullets */
}
.videos .video {
    display: inline-block; /* videos side by side as long as there is space */
    width: 245px; /* 980px site width /4 = 245px = 4 videos in one row */
}
```

A sticky strip line at the bottom could be:

```
<div class="strip-line-bottom"></div>
```

and css for it

```
.strip-line-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: url(path/to/image.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

For detailed information you'll have to provide some more info ;-)